# How to activate multiple L.markerClusterGroup() using L.control.layers in leafletjs, instead of just toggling?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have set up a leafletjs map that uses the MarkerClusters plugin. I want the option to remove a group of markers from the map.

I have tried creating multiple marker clusters and then using `L.control.layers()` to control which clusters appear on the map. This allows me to toggle between the two marker clusters, but not show both at the same time, and then deselect one.

Here are two clusters. Really there are 1000s of points in the real version

```
var addressPoints1 = [
[47.439813,-122.289544,"point a"],
[47.650524,-122.322279,"point b"]];

var addressPoints2[
[47.631938,-122.321723,"point c"]
[47.631859,-122.321548,"point d"]];
```

In the `<body>`, I have this

```
        var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors.'
            }),
            latlng = L.latLng(47.6, -122.32);

        var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 12, layers: [tiles]});

        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

        for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints1.length; i++) {
            var a = addressPoints1[i];
            var title = a[2];
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
            marker.bindPopup(title);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
        }

    //AND
        var markers2 = L.markerClusterGroup();

        for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints2.length; i++) {
            var a = addressPoints2[i];
            var title = a[2];
            var marker2 = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
            marker2.bindPopup(title);
            markers2.addLayer(marker2);
        }

var overlays = { 
 "Cluster 1": markers,
"Cluster 2": markers2
 }; 

 L.control.layers(overlays).addTo(map); 

map.addLayer(markers);
    </script>
```